# I seems to have error with boolean equals in the if-statements and in removeDie I have problem with removing one dice, how to solve these two issues?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, boolean

I need see if printCup and removeDie return false if the cup is empty and remove one dice from array or the cup, I am trying -- on removeDie but its not useful
I tried using if with == but it gave me error, therefore I switched to equals.
About the removeDie, I tried for, -1 from the array but it does not work.
I appreciate for some advice on this one
Thanks in advance.

```
public class IndexDie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Skapar en tärning och skriver ut den");
        Die dice1 = new Die();
        dice1.printDie();

        System.out.println("Skapar en kopp med 3 tärningar och skriver ut koppen");
        Cup cup = new Cup(3);
        cup.printCup();

        System.out.println("lägger 2 tärningar och skriver ut koppen igen");
        cup.addDie();
        cup.addDie();
        cup.printCup();

        System.out.println("Slår alla tärningar i koppen och skriver ut koppen igen,dessutom summan");
        cup.roll();
        cup.printCup();
        System.out.println("Summan blir: " + cup.sum());

        System.out.println("Tar bort 3 tärningar i koppen och skriver ut den");
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.printCup();

        if (cup.removeDie().equals( false) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.removeDie().equals(false) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.removeDie().equals( false) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.printCup().equals( false) {
            System.out.println("error tom kopp!");
        }

    }

}
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cup {

    private ArrayList<Die> dice;

    public Cup(int x) {
        dice = new ArrayList<Die>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            dice.add(new Die());

        }
    }

    public void addDie() {
        dice.add(new Die());

    }

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + dice.get(i).value();

        }
        return sum;
    }

    public void roll() {
        for (int p = 0; p < dice.size(); p++) {
            dice.get(p).roll();
        }

    }

    boolean ok = true;

    public void removeDie() {
        for (int x = 0; x < dice.size(); x--) {
            dice.add(new Die());
            ok = false;
        }

    }

    public void printCup() {
        System.out.println("Tärning: " + dice);
        ok = false;
    }

}
public class Die {

    private int die;



    public void roll() {
        this.die =1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    }

    public int value() {
        return this.die;

    }

    public void printDie() {
        System.out.println(this.die);


    }



}
```

Comment: You are trying to do `cup.removeDie().equals(false)` but `cup.removeDie()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It seems there's a language barrier here, but statements like "it's not useful" and "it gave me error" aren't terribly specific about the problem.  We can appreciate that it may be frustrating, but please be specific about a particular error.  Even if your code has *many* errors, understanding and correcting just one can easily help you fix the rest.  What *specific* error happens on what *specific* line of code and what don't you understand about that error?

Comment: if (cup.removeDie().equals( false) {
            System.out.println("The cup is empty, there is nothing to remove");

Comment: I think you are facing language issue, Do you want to remove die from the cup using `cup.removeDie` method and want to check that if it is empty or not? then you should implement the method like `cup.isEmpty()` which returns true or false. and your `removeDie()` method is wrong, it should delete the last die from the arraylist. rather than you are adding more new dies to the list

Comment: if-statements lines are giving me errors

Comment: But the instructions of my teachers said we are not allowed to use cup.IsEmpty() or another method

Answer (score 2):

Your method `removeDie` is type `void`, it means that it doesn't return anything.

You should do something like that :

```
public boolean removeDie() {
    boolean ok = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < dice.size(); x--) {
        dice.add(new Die());
        ok = false;
    }

    return ok;
}
```

and then

```
if(!cup.removeDie()){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @AdamLord, please consider accepting this answer as it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return a `boolean` from `cup.removeDie()`. May be you can do in this way:

```
public boolean removeDie() {
    for (int x = 0; x < dice.size(); x--) {
        return dice.add(new Die());
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I am not sure about your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class IndexDie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Skapar en tärning och skriver ut den");
        Die dice1 = new Die();
        dice1.printDie();

        System.out.println("Skapar en kopp med 3 tärningar och skriver ut koppen");
        Cup cup = new Cup(3);
        cup.printCup();

        System.out.println("lägger 2 tärningar och skriver ut koppen igen");
        cup.addDie();
        cup.addDie();
        cup.printCup();

        System.out.println("Slår alla tärningar i koppen och skriver ut koppen igen,dessutom summan");
        cup.roll();
        cup.printCup();
        System.out.println("Summan blir: " + cup.sum());

        System.out.println("Tar bort 3 tärningar i koppen och skriver ut den");
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.removeDie();
        cup.printCup();

        if (cup.removeDie() == (false)) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.removeDie() == (false)) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.removeDie() == (false)) {
            System.out.println("Koppen är redan tom,finns inget att ta bort");
        }
        if (cup.printCup() == (false)) {
            System.out.println("error tom kopp!");
        }

    }

}
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cup {

    private ArrayList<Die> dice;

    public Cup(int x) {
        dice = new ArrayList<Die>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            dice.add(new Die());

        }
    }

    public void addDie() {
        dice.add(new Die());

    }

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + dice.get(i).value();

        }
        return sum;
    }

    public void roll() {
        for (int p = 0; p < dice.size(); p++) {
            dice.get(p).roll();
        }

    }

    public boolean removeDie() {
        for (int x = dice.size(); x <=1 ; x--) {
            return dice.add(new Die());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean printCup() {

        System.out.println("Tärning: " + dice);
        return false;
    }

}
public class Die {

    private int die;



    public void roll() {
        this.die =1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);

    }

    public int value() {
        return this.die;

    }

    public void printDie() {
        System.out.println(this.die);


    }



}
```

if anyone interested how I solved the problem, still needs a few changes but thanks for the help guys